# How to draw tow donut Graph with two different color using aChartEngine in Android?

Tags: android, achartengine, donut-chart

I am using aChartEngine Library to draw donut in my android application.I want to make two donut - one inside another with two different color. But I am unable to make them with two different color.This is my donut class which draw donut in LinearLayout.

```
public class PunchStatGraph {
private GraphicalView mChartView2;
static int count = 2;

int[] Mycolors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#D4272D"),
        Color.parseColor("#6F1717") };
String[] average = { "SPEED", "FORCE"};
String[] max = { "SPEED", "FORCE"};

public Intent execute(Context context, LinearLayout parent, double avg_values[],double max_values[]) {
    parent.removeAllViews();
    int[] colors = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        colors[i] = Mycolors[i];
    }
    DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setShowLabels(false);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);// Disable User Interaction
    renderer.setScale((float) 1.4);
    renderer.setInScroll(true); //To avoid scroll Shrink        
    renderer.setStartAngle(90);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);


    MultipleCategorySeries categorySeries = new MultipleCategorySeries(
            "Punch Graph");
    categorySeries.add(average, avg_values);
    categorySeries.add(max, max_values);

    mChartView2 = ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartView(context,
            categorySeries, renderer);

    parent.addView(mChartView2);

    return ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartIntent(context, categorySeries,
            renderer, null);
}

protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

    }
    return renderer;
}
}
```

Check Image also.Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you didn't manage to get to work.

Comment: I didn't manage two donut with two different color.